# Linux install fails, both Ubuntu 18.04 and Fedora 29

Tags: ubuntu, fedora, boot, system-installation

I have Windows 10 and i wanted to install Ubuntu 18.04, preferably on the same drive as Windows, or if need be in another drive.

I tried first to make the LiveUSB with Unetbootin which failed twice; the first attempt resulting in a USB which would not boot, the second would boot but its install failed. I also tried Rufus and LinuxLive USB with no results, then i tried to make a Fedora LiveUSB in LinuxLive which also failed.

Ubuntu's LiveUSB made with Unetbootin, failed with these error messages:

[image]

[image]

And when II tried Fedora it failed with these errors: 
[image]

My BIOS version is Award Software International, Inc. F6, 30/05/2012.
CPU is AMD64 Family 21 Model 2 Stepping 0 @ ~4Ghz.
Graphic card is an AMD Radeon R9 Series 200.
Edit:
 Motherboard: Gigabyte GA-970A-UD3 rev 1.2

Comment: These are all complaints about BIOS bugs. Make sure you update the BIOS. And you also need to boot with UEFI.

Comment: Please click on [edit] above and add to your original post which motherboard you have.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I saw something about this searching the error in internet but i don't know where i choose between LEGACY or UEFI. I think it should be in the bios options but i don't see anything about boot mode and choose between those

Comment: Your motherboard supports UEFI booting. And it has a BIOS update available.

Comment: I updated my Motherboard with Gigabyte APP Center and despite a bunch of messages saying ¨this driver can't relese to failure¨ looks like all went good but i am still withou knowing how to set booting to UEFI

Comment: @MichaelHampton Actually i have edited that my motherboard is revision 1.2 and looking at gigabyte support i realised that says "Patented DualBIOS with Hybrid EFI technology for 3TB HDD support" i suppose EFI is the same than UEFI isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you could get the Ubuntu one working if you get into the grub menu editor by pressing e when the grub menu is up then edit the entry that you are booting into, to include acpi=off. Like it is done here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/160036/how-do-i-disable-acpi-when-booting this should help.

Comment: I can't get to grub, After reboot the pc i go for choose the boot method i choose USB and the boots throught the USB where i have Ubuntu but then stay with the garnet screen of ubuntu like 10 or 15 seconds and then appers the terminal screen with all that stuff

Comment: As soon as you hit enter for choosing usb, hit shift as quick as possable and hold it until you see something that tells you the widow has past.

Comment: Also insted of using Unetbootin or the like try: mount to find the usb device id then sudo umount /dev/sd<?><?> where <?><?> is a letter followed by a number of the drive. Then, next:  dd bs=4M if="/path/to/iso.iso" of="/dev/sd<?>" conv=fdatasync.

Comment: I am gonna try the shift thing but i can't try the mount and unmount thing cause im in windows and i don't have (or i don't know where is it) terminal

Comment: Okey if i keep presed shift after select boot throught USB it appears the screen of "loading operating system" and then appear the word "boot:" waiting for write something but anything else i can exit from there pressing escape but nothing changes